# SharePoint Error: File Not found and goes to Web parts maintenance page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, error, filenotfoundexception

I am getting the following error when I visit the sharepoint site or document library. I didn't change any settings or added new code or change the style sheet. It was working fine few mins ago and suddenly this happened.

"

```
File Not Found.

Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator.
```

"

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to delete those web parts that doesn't work.
you have just to append ?contents=1 at the end of the URL of respective page and SharePoint will open the Web Part Maintenance Page for it.

For example, if the URL of problematic page is
http://mysite.code.com/Test/default.aspx

then Web Part Maintenance Page url will be
http://mysite.code.com/Test/default.aspx?contents=1

Comment: How to know that which web part dosent work?